# How do i know that my results are good when working with a CNN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to classify time based bio signals using CNN. Now my classifier says that it has an accuracy of 91%, which would beat the the record w.r.t these signals So i want to find out if my results are genuine or not. I am skeptical about the result as the way it trains is also funny. There aren't many explanations online as it if the way it is training is right or wrong.

```
#This is the code while printing results....
score = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=1)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

```
#i had taken one_hot_vector so i needed to change the format here
pred_y = model.predict(test_x)
print(pred_y.shape)
predy = np.argmax(pred_y, axis=1).T
print(confusion_matrix(testy, predy))
print(classification_report(testy, predy))
```

This is the training process and its output:

```
Train on 980 samples, validate on 180 samples

Epoch 1/1000

 - 3s - loss: 2.4064 - acc: 0.8240 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1762 - val_loss: 2.4179 - val_acc: 0.8256 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1737

Epoch 2/1000

 - 1s - loss: 2.4962 - acc: 0.8241 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1759 - val_loss: 2.3047 - val_acc: 0.8289 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1716

Epoch 3/1000

 - 1s - loss: 2.4027 - acc: 0.8250 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1750 - val_loss: 2.1278 - val_acc: 0.8267 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1736

Epoch 4/1000

 - 1s - loss: 1.1608 - acc: 0.8455 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1780 - val_loss: 0.3370 - val_acc: 0.8983 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1792

Epoch 5/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.3330 - acc: 0.8990 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1800 - val_loss: 0.3248 - val_acc: 0.9000 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1798

Epoch 6/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.3263 - acc: 0.9000 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1800 - val_loss: 0.3247 - val_acc: 0.9000 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1798

.........
.........
.........
Epoch 993/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0430 - acc: 0.9832 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0282 - val_loss: 0.0374 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0178

Epoch 994/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0381 - acc: 0.9871 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0246 - val_loss: 0.0376 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0177

Epoch 995/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0379 - acc: 0.9852 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0250 - val_loss: 0.0376 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0177

Epoch 996/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0432 - acc: 0.9842 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0282 - val_loss: 0.0375 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0177

Epoch 997/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0352 - acc: 0.9874 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0248 - val_loss: 0.0376 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0175

Epoch 998/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0395 - acc: 0.9850 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0256 - val_loss: 0.0378 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0174

Epoch 999/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0371 - acc: 0.9860 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0250 - val_loss: 0.0380 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0173

Epoch 1000/1000

 - 1s - loss: 0.0353 - acc: 0.9873 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0243 - val_loss: 0.0379 - val_acc: 0.9894 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0173
```

The model structure is as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_49 (Conv1D)           (None, 798, 10)           310       
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_50 (Conv1D)           (None, 796, 5)            155       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_25 (MaxPooling (None, 159, 5)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_25 (Flatten)         (None, 795)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_25 (Dropout)         (None, 795)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             (None, 10)                7960      
=================================================================
Total params: 8,425
Trainable params: 8,425
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Test set results is as follows:

```
Test loss: 0.3470249831676483
Test accuracy: 0.9183333237965902
(120, 10)

[[7 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]

 [0 4 1 1 1 3 0 1 0 1]

 [2 0 8 0 0 0 2 0 0 0]

 [1 0 1 3 2 1 1 0 2 1]

 [0 0 0 0 8 2 0 0 1 1]

 [0 5 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 0]

 [4 0 1 0 0 0 6 0 0 1]

 [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 7 1 1]

 [0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 9 0]

 [1 0 2 2 0 0 2 0 0 5]]
```

The confusion matrix and classification results are as follows:

```
precision    recall  f1-score   support
0       0.44      0.58      0.50        12
1       0.36      0.33      0.35        12
2       0.44      0.67      0.53        12
3       0.43      0.25      0.32        12
4       0.67      0.67      0.67        12
5       0.54      0.58      0.56        12
6       0.50      0.50      0.50        12
7       0.88      0.58      0.70        12
8       0.69      0.75      0.72        12
9       0.50      0.42      0.45        12

   micro avg       0.53      0.53      0.53       120

   macro avg       0.54      0.53      0.53       120

weighted avg       0.54      0.53      0.53       120
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: As it's not specifically about coding, this question might be better off on https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: @David Hempy :My question in simpler words would be...how do i interpret my results and how do i know that my cnn isnt overfitting?

Comment: Your question is very general and opinion-based. It may not be a good fit for StackOverflow. I think G. Anderson's comment above is on-point.